# Fluxo a custo mínimo

Tags: otimização, redes, grafo

Como faço para encontrar o fluxo de custo mínimo em um dígrafo cujos arcos possuem um limite inferior e superior para o fluxo e um custo por cada unidade de fluxo?

Obs: Não usar programação linear.
Inicialmente não há um fluxo viável.
Somente a oferta do vértice fornecedor é conhecido.
Suponha que sempre haverá um fluxo viável de custo mínimo.

Comment: Olá, Michael. Seja bem-vindo. Isso parece ser dever de casa. Mostre o que já fez e em que exatamente está tendo problemas, senão fica parecendo que você apenas quer que façamos o seu trabalho para você.

Comment: Isso é um desafio do DIMACS para fluxo em redes http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/DIMACS_mcf.htm só que eu quero resolver sem usar o simplex e seus derivados